# passing data using prepareForSegue not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm passing 2 values to a PFQueryViewContoller using prepareForSegue. Both of the properties are defined in the header file (public). You can see in the code below that I pass them twice (once without testing to see if county is null and once checking if it's null. I did this just to emphasize that the issue isn't related to whether county is getting set elsewhere in my code prior to prepareforsegue getting called. Does anyone have any idea why this might not be working? It's probably a very silly error. I've checked the name of the segue (even copied and pasted it into the prepareforsegue method in case there's a typo I missed). Also, the destination viewcontroller is not embedded in any other view controller. This is a custom segue in case that matters.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"toPizzaSpots"])
{
    // Get reference to the destination view controller
    PizzaSpotTVC *vc = [segue destinationViewController];


    // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
    vc.county = self.county;
    vc.no = 8;
    if (self.county){

    vc.county = self.county;
    vc.no = 8;
    }

   }
  }
```

Comment: By the way, I inserted NSLogs inside the if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"toPizzaSpots"]) conditional to make sure the code was getting called when I segued and it is being called. My PFQueryViewContoller has a method called initWithCoder, does this have anything to do with why the data is not making it into my destinationViewController?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Does the segue successfully execute, but the data isn't passed?

Comment: In what way is the data transfer not working? At what point do you determine in `PizzaSpotTVC` that the data has not been transferred?

Comment: Yea, the app transitions like normal to the PFQueryViewContoller but then inside that viewcontroller when I NSLog the values of the properties I set they're null.  - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];
    if (self) {

Comment: Everything else inside of that initWithCoder method executes just fine

Comment: What causes this segue to be invoked? Is the segue made directly from a button or cell, or is it made from the controller?

Comment: It's a swipe gesture right now but in the future I intend to use a button instead (bc swiping up is accidentally invoking the iOS setting panel)

Comment: Also, are you checking the values in initWithCoder? If so, that's too early -- check them in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Ah ok. Well that answers the question. I'm checking them in initWithCoder. Thanks.

Comment: Hey rdelmar any tips on how to get my score a little higher so I can upvote an answer or do normal things on this site? I try to participate and answer questions but it seems like it takes forever to get anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Looking at property values passed in through `prepareForSegue:sender:` can't be done inside an init method. By the time `prepareForSegue` is called, the destination view controller's init method has already been called. The values of those properties will have been set b y the time viewDidLoad is called, so it's safe to access them there.

Answer (score 0):

InitWithCoder is the very first method called in the ViewController lifecycle when PFQueryViewContoller is created. In order to access the properties set by prepareForSegue method you need to access them in the viewDidLoad method. Thanks to rdelmar for answering the question. FYI for anyone else dealing with this issue, if you change a property in the viewDidLoad method that your Parse query relies on (e.g., to pull from the proper table in your Parse database), the viewDidLoad executes in enough time to send this parseClassName to Parse to properly execute the query. This was my concern initially when I tried to access the property in the initWithCoder method and it was so early it wasn't working- I thought it needed to be in there to get the Parse query to work (but it doesn't- viewDidLoad is amply early enough)